# Linux: set date through command line

Tags: linux, date, clock

How to change the system date in Linux ?

I want to change:

- Only Year
- Only Month
- Only Date
- Any combination of above three

Comment: You can use e.g. `date --set='-2 years'` to set the clock back two years, leaving all other elements identical. You can change month and day of month the same way. I haven't checked what happens if that calculation results in a datetime that doesn't actually exist, e.g. during a DST switchover, but the behaviour ought to be identical to the usual "set both date and time to concrete values" behaviour.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to set the date to the current time, you could do `sudo ntpd -gq` to have the system update automatically using the ntp service.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Use [`date -s`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date):

```
date -s '2014-12-25 12:34:56'
```

Run that as root or under `sudo`. Changing only one of the year/month/day is more of a challenge and will involve repeating bits of the current date. There are also GUI date tools built in to the major desktop environments, usually accessed through the clock.

To change only part of the time, you can use command substitution in the date string:

```
date -s "2014-12-25 $(date +%H:%M:%S)"
```

will change the date, but keep the time. See [`man date`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) for formatting details to construct other combinations: the individual components are `%Y`, `%m`, `%d`, `%H`, `%M`, and `%S`.

Comment: I don't want to change the time

Comment: There's no option to do that. You can use `date -s "2014-12-25 $(date +%H:%M:%S)"` to change the date and reuse the current time, though.

Comment: came here and hours as well as minutes were matching current time. – nice

Comment: `date: cannot set date: Invalid argument`

Comment: @MichaelHomer @SHW it is possible to change only the date with a command like `date -s 2018-01-01`. Someone shared this in an answer also: https://superuser.com/questions/870068/how-to-set-system-time-on-kali-linux#1162962

Comment: @baptx On the assumption that it is exactly midnight, yes.

Comment: I try to change but its not changing:-
 $ sudo date --set="2015-09-30 10:05:59.990"
Wed Sep 30 10:05:59 +0530 2015
$ date
Thu May 23 15:10:37 +0530 2019

Comment: @MichaelHomer about `date -s "2014-12-25 $(date +%H:%M:%S)"` seems a contradiction about the _answer_ vs _comment_ indicate. Consider to update your answer, seems is correct the comment's content. So this 'contradiction' makes confuse the second part of your answer

Comment: @ManuelJordan I don't know what update you're suggesting.

Comment: @MichaelHomer `date -s "2014-12-25 $(date +%H:%M:%S)"` about in your comment updates only the date and reuses the time, right? but in the answer seems the inverse because says/indicates `To change only part of the time, you can use command substitution in the date string:` ... there the possible contradiction

Answer (score 60):

**System time**

You can use `date` to set the system date. The GNU implementation of `date` (as found on most non-embedded Linux-based systems) accepts many different formats to set the time, here a few examples:

set only the year:

```
date -s 'next year'
date -s 'last year'
```

set only the month:

```
date -s 'last month'
date -s 'next month'
```

set only the day:

```
date -s 'next day'
date -s 'tomorrow'
date -s 'last day'
date -s 'yesterday'
date -s 'friday'
```

set all together:

```
date -s '2009-02-13 11:31:30' #that's a magical timestamp
```

**Hardware time**

Now the system time is set, but you may want to sync it with the hardware clock:

Use `--show` to print the hardware time:

```
hwclock --show
```

You can set the hardware clock to the current system time:

```
hwclock --hctosys
```

Or the system time to the hardware clock

```
hwclock --systohc
```

Comment: Bonus points for illustrating the non-obvious ways you can set the date with examples and for pointing out the difference between the "system time" and the "hardware clock". Very helpful answer!

Comment: I think you confused hctosys and systohc. hctosys means "Set system time from hardware clock" and systohc means "Set hardware clock from system time".

Answer (score 10):

The command to *to change the system date* is `date`.

There are two ways to [call the date command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)(in Linux):

```
   date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]
   date [-u|--utc|--universal] [MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]
```

## Easy

The easiest way is to use `date -s` as it allows the use of *simple* **relative** dates

```
 $ date -s yesterday; date
 date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
 Sat Jan  5 07:21:07 EST 2019
 Sun Jan  6 07:21:07 EST 2019
```

The date did not change because it was executed with a limited user `$`. If you actually want the date changed, use root (`#`) or sudo:

```
 $ sudo date -s yesterday; date
 Sat Jan  5 07:21:07 EST 2019
 Sat Jan  5 07:21:07 EST 2019
```

So, changing any part of a **relative** date is as easy as naming it:

```
 $ date -s "5 years ago"
 Mon Jan  6 08:26:26 EST 2014

 $ date -s "+6 months"
 Sat Jul  6 08:28:39 EDT 2019

 $ date -s "+3 hours -13 minutes"
 Sun Jan  6 11:16:59 AST 2019
```

Absolute dates are a bit more complex as they need more detail:

```
 $ date -s "2001-07-23 10:11:12"
```

Or, you can use the date command twice:

```
 $ date -s "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
```

replace any of the `%` by a valid value and the date will be set (only as root).

```
 $ date -s "$(date +'%Y-11-%d %H:%M:%S')"
 Wed Nov  6 08:37:15 EST 2019
```

## direct

The second date call form is used to **directly** change the system date.

```
 date [-u|--utc|--universal] [MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]
```

So :

```
 date 11230812              # MMDDhhmm
```

Will set the date to the 23th of November at 08h and 12min.

[BSD has a similar command](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/date/) but a different format ([[[[[cc]yy]mm]dd]HH]MM[.ss]).

Try `date` as a limited user to see what it would do (without changing anything):

```
 $ date 11230812
 date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
 Sat Nov 23 08:12:00 EST 2019
```

Or, if you actually want to change the date, as root:

```
 # date 11230812
 # date
 Sat Nov 23 08:12:00 EST 2019
```

Note that services like NTP or chrony will be affected. And, if restarted will reset the date back to the real one.

Add a YY to set the year:

```
 $ date 1123081222
 date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
 Wed Nov 23 08:12:00 EST 2022
```

Or a CCYY to set year **and** century:

```
 $ date 112308121982
 date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
 Tue Nov 23 08:12:00 EST 1982
```

Answer (score 5):

You change the date with the `date` command.  However, the command expects a full date as the argument:

```
# date -s "20141022 09:45"
Wed Oct 22 09:45:00 BST 2014
```

To change part of the date, output the current date with the date part that you want to change as a string and all others as date formatting variables.  Then pass that to the `date -s` command to set it:

```
# date -s "$(date +'%Y12%d %H:%M')"
Mon Dec 22 10:55:03 GMT 2014
```

changes the month to the 12th month - December.

The date formats are:

- `%Y` - Year
- `%m` - Month
- `%d` - Day
- `%H` - Hour
- `%M` - Minute

Comment: I try to change but its not changing:- 
$ sudo date --set="2015-09-30 10:05:59.990" Wed Sep 30 10:05:59 +0530 2015 
$ date 
Thu May 23 15:10:37 +0530 2019

Answer (score 3):

*As of December 2022:*

You may **disable NTP sync** before **actual date change**:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp 0
sudo timedatectl set-time "2022-12-03 $(date +%H:%M:%S)"
```

When date modification is no longer necessary, you should enable NTP sync again to auto update system date:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp 1
```

Comment: This applies only to installations that use systemd. Also, once you turn off ntp, you can still just use the `date` command to set the date if needed (depending on the purpose).

Comment: This saved me some time while debugging issues in Ubuntu 22.04. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For ones like me running ESXI 5.1, here's what the system answered me

```
~ # date -s "2016-03-23 09:56:00"
date: invalid date '2016-03-23 09:56:00'
```

I had to uses a specific ESX command instead :

```
esxcli system time set  -y 2016 -M 03 -d 23  -H 10 -m 05 -s 00
```

Comment: Thanks for the -1, but would you mind explaining *why* ?  If you got a better/more complete/more exact answer, feel free to comment.

Answer (score -2):

I used the date command and time format listed below to successfully set the date from the terminal shell command performed on Android Things which uses the Linux Kernal.

date 092615002017.00

MMDDHHMMYYYY.SS

MM - Month - 09

DD - Day - 26

HH - Hour - 15

MM - Min - 00

YYYY - Year - 2017

.SS - second - 00

Comment: Since this does not work with either GNU or BSD `date`, could you please add more info about what system this is relevant for and how it's relevant to this particular question.